# Distribute list of bits into given amount of slots

Tags: javascript, math

Given a bitfield like the following (numbers can only be 1 or 0):

```
const bits = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I want to produce a list of N average values where N is an arbitrary number.

In our example above, given N is 4, the result would be `[1, 0.5, 0, 0.5]`. (group the array 2 by 2 and then calculate the average number of each group).

If, instead, N was 2, the result would be `[0.75, 0.25]`.

I have been using the following code so far:

```
const average = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / args.length;

const averageNumbers = Ramda.splitEvery(Math.floor(bits.length / N), bits).map(nums => average(nums))
```

The problem is that the above doesn't work in case my `bits` array is composed of 696 values and I need 150 average numbers, because I end up having 174 numbers instead of 150.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what exactly does this `splitEvery` function do? Assuming it is some sort of "array-chunk", that divides the input array into chunks of the passed length - `floor(696 / 150)` is 4, and 696 / 4 is 174.

Comment: @CBroe yes splitEvery is just the ramda utility, I know my math is wrong, I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: do you have an example with matching bit values? why do you get the result of `[1, 0.5, 0, 0.5]`?

Comment: @NinaScholz since I expect 4 average numbers I group the array 2 by 2 and make the average of each group.

Comment: what if the array has not the same divisor?

Comment: @NinaScholz I need an approximation, the important is that I get the correct amount of average values. I suppose the numbers could even get divided in order to get the expected amount of them in order to maintain the correct precision but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you end up with 174 numbers instead of 150 because `floor(696 / 150)` divides the bit field into 174 chunks of 4 bits.

To get an approximate value for the averages, you can first "expand" the bit field to a length that is a multiple of N before taking the averages.

```
// Factor is the lowest number to expand bits by for its length to be a multiple of N
const factor = lcm(bits.length, N) / bits.length;

// Expand bits by the factor
const expandedBits = bits.map(bit => Array(factor).fill(bit)).flat(1);

const averages = splitEvery(Math.floor(expandedBits.length / N), expandedBits).map(nums => average(...nums));

// averages.length should now always be N
```